# Why order of Instantiating of Angular Components is not in expected order with if condition?

Tags: javascript, angular

I cannot find anywhere in the docs why the order of instantiating of Angular Components is not in expected order with **if** condition? I was expecting it to come in the same order as they are written in the console also. i.e 1 2 3 4 5 (HTML wise it is correct)
but it is coming as 3 4 5 1 2

Although I have made assumption after observing this behavior that **if** condition delays execution comparing with without it but could not find the reason/documentation for it.

Slackblitz Link to verify this behavior:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-looping-data-sbnayy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect **any** order if there is nothing written in the docs?

Comment: I have asked here to get the reason for this behavior(which I couldn't find/expecting). Do you know its reason?

Comment: The reason for this behavior is the way Angular is programmed and I assume you can't find anything in the docs is because the order is undefined. It can be changed by the context, the environment, the view or by directives. It's probably almost impossible to predict the order in a complex application.

Comment: I don't know why it works the way it works, but I wonder if it is relevant to you, because it should not be relevant. Are you experiencing any problems related to the order of execution? If so we might be able to help you address that problem if you explain it.

Comment: yeah, actually I have a component(Tabs) which is kind of registering itself in the order of it is defined(with the help of Service which is incrementing index from the previous value). And few of tabs can come conditionally. And this is breaking this logic. I want to circumvent this problem with exiting implementation if there is. One way is to put if condition in all tabs.

Comment: _"Why order of Instantiating of Angular Components is not in expected order with if condition?"_ I'd say the answer is: because your expectations are wrong. You can't expect the components to be evaluated from top to bottom in all cases. Now we are at a new question. You should ask a new question with [mcve] and the expected behavior. The comment section is not intended to discuss multiple questions.

Comment: @TusharKhanna You could be using ContentChildren instead. It is ordered.

Comment: I was assisting my original problem with an example so that I can help understand the original intent to identify where it is coming from. Nevermind.

Comment: @silvermind Just to answer your question, before I may ask another specific question regarding this. I cannot use ContentChildren, registering of tab happens inside itself(in OnInit) with the help of TabService. This reply was just to help others that ContentChildren will not help me here. Sorry if I might have confused. Just wanted to add context. Period.

Comment: @TusharKhanna No problem. I was not being judgmental. Just asking, because we might be able to help you fix your problem in another way. Perhaps you could use an index input field for your tabs to specify an order. Maybe not as clean as you want, but it could help you workaround the problem with the current workings.

Comment: Thankyou, @Silvermind for making me re-think. Actually, I already was taking index optionally but always pushing the Tab to the end of array(even when index is passed), that was the mistake.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) act that way because they are based on [<ng-template>](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template)

This:

```
<hello name="1" *ngIf="true"></hello>
```

just simplified syntax of

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="true">
    <hello name="1"></hello>
</ng-template>
```

[<ng-template>](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template) won't be rendered while it's not instructed to do so.

What exactly happens in your case:

1. *app.component* has created and comes through *OnInit => DoCheck => AfterContentInit => AfterContentChecked* lifecycle hooks.
2. *hello.component*s are content (children) of *app.component* and they shall be initialized, but under the hood **ngIf* wraps "hello1" and "hello2" into [<ng-template>](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template). Remember that.
3. Now *app.component*'s children come through the same lifecycle hooks (*OnInit* to *AfterContentChecked*). Angular does not insert [<ng-template>](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template)'s into the DOM but placeholder for that (you can see it in the document tree as a comment):

   <!--bindings={
   "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
   }-->
4. Then "hello3", "hello4" and "hello5" are initialized, inserted into the DOM and execute *console.log(this.name)*
5. Time for *ngIf* directives and *hello.components* (3 to 5) initialize they own content. At this time *hello.components* (1 and 2) are initialized each inside their own *ngIf* directive, inserted into the DOM after their placeholders and also execute *console.log(this.name)*
6. Then *AfterViewInit => AfterViewChecked* hooks bubbles up from the very deep children in the tree and you see rendered page